# footer height is too small in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, material-design-lite

I'm looking here at the element `footer.mdl-mini-footer`. All given sizes were measured using F12 developer tools in Responsive Mode with a screen size of `768x884` (Chrome's Tablet breakpoint size).

In Firefox, the element `footer.mdl-mini-footer` has a size of `width: 736px; height: 36px;`.

In Chrome, the element `footer.mdl-mini-footer` has a size of `width: 736px; height: 10.438px;`.

The key point here is the height difference. In both browsers, the child element `ul.mdl-mini-footer__link-list` has a size of `width: 268px; height: 36px;`, causing the footer's content to sink beneath the `footer` element.

Note that the `style="padding: 8px 16px"` on the footer element *is not* required for this issue to occur, it just makes it more visible by cutting down on the default padding provided by Material Design Lite of `32px 16px`. Specifically, the issue is that **the footer's height decreases in Chrome as the page's content has to scroll more**. This *does not* happen in Firefox, and is the desired behavior.

For completeness sake, I also tested the page in Microsoft Edge, which behaves exactly as Firefox. Also, changing Chrome's zoom level to 125% to better match Firefox's zoom level only exacerbates the problem with a new footer height of `8.297px`.

**Why does this happen only in Chrome, and how can I prevent it?**

Stack Snippet in Firefox:
[image: Firefox]

Stack Snippet in Chrome:
[image: Chrome]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-- Material Design Lite -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.deep_purple-blue.min.css">
  <script defer="" src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="mdl-layout__container">
    <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout">
      <main class="mdl-layout__content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam egestas, magna ac ultrices hendrerit, risus lorem accumsan justo, at finibus orci odio at sapien. Morbi eu placerat nisl. Nunc rhoncus ut risus nec eleifend. Nulla facilisi. Morbi
          nec nisi facilisis, maximus ligula sed, facilisis enim. Suspendisse fermentum venenatis tincidunt. Maecenas semper consectetur vestibulum. Morbi eget molestie magna. Duis quis neque interdum, elementum risus ac, interdum urna. Nunc fermentum
          non nulla vel pharetra. In ullamcorper ac ipsum ut convallis. Morbi bibendum nisi vitae quam commodo porta.</p>
        <p>Nam facilisis finibus libero vel consequat. Cras eu magna in dui ullamcorper aliquet nec vestibulum mi. Nam rutrum justo ac risus imperdiet consectetur. Donec pellentesque sapien nec euismod ullamcorper. Nam efficitur quam vitae justo convallis,
          a aliquet justo finibus. Pellentesque auctor finibus neque sed dapibus. Ut maximus interdum risus ut viverra. Quisque varius, augue et cursus efficitur, nisl arcu maximus sapien, vel tempor erat elit at turpis. Nullam imperdiet urna eget elit
          dignissim, ut feugiat nibh lacinia. Aliquam vel cursus est. Praesent tristique mauris a ex viverra, at vehicula nibh laoreet.</p>
        <p>Curabitur lacinia, justo ac placerat porta, lectus nulla aliquam nisi, sit amet elementum enim ipsum vitae tortor. Donec eu ultrices tellus. Nam et quam nisl. Nulla facilisi. Donec turpis velit, tristique et ultrices sit amet, blandit vel tellus.
          Nam ultricies posuere odio in pretium. Integer semper, lacus at pulvinar condimentum, nibh nibh ornare dui, vel tincidunt mauris turpis at sapien. Nunc ultrices sollicitudin diam ut semper. Nulla quis quam fringilla, pretium erat eu, hendrerit
          tellus. Ut lacinia elit eu leo lobortis tincidunt. Sed vel gravida purus. Fusce ultrices libero ante, sit amet finibus sem eleifend ac. Etiam ullamcorper placerat orci, id vulputate sapien blandit eget. Proin eget hendrerit tellus, sit amet
          venenatis dui.</p>
        <p>Nullam ut diam et ante euismod suscipit. Sed aliquet rutrum pharetra. Sed quis orci malesuada, elementum tellus id, aliquet eros. Donec ut nisl sit amet erat ornare finibus. Aliquam id tincidunt augue. Sed tincidunt maximus sem at dictum. Fusce
          in quam efficitur, finibus sapien a, convallis felis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus tristique auctor diam, euismod cursus mi. Phasellus quis
          posuere mi. Integer ut rhoncus massa. Curabitur quis consequat sapien, sit amet malesuada mauris. Vestibulum in tristique ex, ut fermentum velit. Nam ac lobortis dui, eget aliquam ligula. Vestibulum vel leo in purus tincidunt luctus non ut orci.</p>
        <p>Integer venenatis vestibulum lorem nec ultrices. In eget commodo velit, in vulputate nisi. Aliquam pulvinar dignissim nisl. Pellentesque congue faucibus enim, a malesuada quam molestie nec. Sed lacinia turpis tellus, eu pretium lectus auctor id.
          Sed porta ipsum eu neque volutpat volutpat. Suspendisse rutrum mi felis, nec vulputate velit vulputate quis. Maecenas mollis lobortis neque, nec vehicula orci. Vivamus fringilla volutpat ligula. Proin eu sem eget orci convallis lobortis. Proin
          id orci luctus, elementum velit eget, pulvinar orci.</p>
        <p>Etiam hendrerit ipsum eros, a semper mi fringilla et. Fusce pretium ac lorem in blandit. Nulla facilisi. Nunc orci lectus, cursus eget semper vitae, interdum non turpis. Suspendisse dolor ante, tincidunt eu urna eu, dapibus consectetur dolor.
          In in tortor et lorem euismod semper. Nullam gravida turpis vel commodo ullamcorper. Vestibulum rutrum consequat tortor at blandit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc eget eleifend lectus.
          Duis mollis aliquet ipsum eget tempus.</p>
        <p>Aliquam viverra neque vitae faucibus posuere. Phasellus facilisis nisl vel risus aliquam commodo. Etiam lacinia laoreet sagittis. Mauris dignissim odio sed diam tempor, dapibus condimentum massa cursus. Integer ut nibh commodo, congue tortor vel,
          imperdiet ex. Morbi quis elementum metus, nec consequat purus. Praesent rutrum efficitur tempus. Phasellus hendrerit luctus magna in vehicula. Vestibulum dictum magna nisi, at lacinia lorem vestibulum et.</p>
        <p>Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus at eleifend ligula. Nam sed placerat nisl, a pulvinar ante. Mauris ac laoreet ante. Aliquam pellentesque leo tortor, sed tempor massa egestas quis. Fusce dictum non turpis sed scelerisque. Nunc tristique nisl ac
          ante tristique venenatis. Quisque quis felis rhoncus, porttitor enim sit amet, facilisis quam. Curabitur non erat ac ante faucibus lobortis eget at lorem. Maecenas eget tempus sapien. Curabitur eu luctus nulla, eu luctus ex. Vestibulum sodales
          enim enim, sit amet tempor ligula laoreet at. Etiam est arcu, elementum et sodales non, tincidunt et sapien. Fusce vitae molestie mi, a bibendum felis. Sed nunc mauris, faucibus vel rutrum ut, lacinia sit amet neque.</p>
        <p>Curabitur blandit lacus ut erat cursus luctus quis blandit ex. Duis eget fringilla risus, et egestas ligula. Pellentesque ligula ante, vulputate in faucibus et, efficitur sed mauris. Aliquam at pretium est, nec tempor mauris. Ut pharetra eget
          neque non dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla blandit tellus vel massa elementum, vel consectetur ligula maximus. Vestibulum rutrum magna sit amet dictum mattis. Morbi varius lacus ac imperdiet fringilla. Suspendisse molestie nibh vitae gravida
          sollicitudin. Suspendisse tempor finibus felis, eu sagittis lorem.</p>
        <p>Sed sodales ultrices facilisis. Phasellus vel massa id neque convallis volutpat vitae sed turpis. Sed ac massa dolor. Sed facilisis nulla suscipit commodo venenatis. In bibendum consectetur rutrum. Duis dapibus, risus sit amet semper pharetra,
          erat dui blandit erat, sit amet rutrum ante est nec enim. Pellentesque lobortis ligula sed fringilla dictum. Proin rhoncus, lacus in facilisis pharetra, lorem leo facilisis metus, ac ornare diam risus sed ipsum. Nullam mattis enim nec odio porttitor
          fermentum vel vel mi. Aliquam lacinia consectetur interdum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam egestas, magna ac ultrices hendrerit, risus lorem accumsan justo, at finibus orci odio at sapien. Morbi eu placerat nisl. Nunc rhoncus ut risus nec eleifend. Nulla facilisi. Morbi
          nec nisi facilisis, maximus ligula sed, facilisis enim. Suspendisse fermentum venenatis tincidunt. Maecenas semper consectetur vestibulum. Morbi eget molestie magna. Duis quis neque interdum, elementum risus ac, interdum urna. Nunc fermentum
          non nulla vel pharetra. In ullamcorper ac ipsum ut convallis. Morbi bibendum nisi vitae quam commodo porta.</p>
        <p>Nam facilisis finibus libero vel consequat. Cras eu magna in dui ullamcorper aliquet nec vestibulum mi. Nam rutrum justo ac risus imperdiet consectetur. Donec pellentesque sapien nec euismod ullamcorper. Nam efficitur quam vitae justo convallis,
          a aliquet justo finibus. Pellentesque auctor finibus neque sed dapibus. Ut maximus interdum risus ut viverra. Quisque varius, augue et cursus efficitur, nisl arcu maximus sapien, vel tempor erat elit at turpis. Nullam imperdiet urna eget elit
          dignissim, ut feugiat nibh lacinia. Aliquam vel cursus est. Praesent tristique mauris a ex viverra, at vehicula nibh laoreet.</p>
        <p>Curabitur lacinia, justo ac placerat porta, lectus nulla aliquam nisi, sit amet elementum enim ipsum vitae tortor. Donec eu ultrices tellus. Nam et quam nisl. Nulla facilisi. Donec turpis velit, tristique et ultrices sit amet, blandit vel tellus.
          Nam ultricies posuere odio in pretium. Integer semper, lacus at pulvinar condimentum, nibh nibh ornare dui, vel tincidunt mauris turpis at sapien. Nunc ultrices sollicitudin diam ut semper. Nulla quis quam fringilla, pretium erat eu, hendrerit
          tellus. Ut lacinia elit eu leo lobortis tincidunt. Sed vel gravida purus. Fusce ultrices libero ante, sit amet finibus sem eleifend ac. Etiam ullamcorper placerat orci, id vulputate sapien blandit eget. Proin eget hendrerit tellus, sit amet
          venenatis dui.</p>
        <p>Nullam ut diam et ante euismod suscipit. Sed aliquet rutrum pharetra. Sed quis orci malesuada, elementum tellus id, aliquet eros. Donec ut nisl sit amet erat ornare finibus. Aliquam id tincidunt augue. Sed tincidunt maximus sem at dictum. Fusce
          in quam efficitur, finibus sapien a, convallis felis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus tristique auctor diam, euismod cursus mi. Phasellus quis
          posuere mi. Integer ut rhoncus massa. Curabitur quis consequat sapien, sit amet malesuada mauris. Vestibulum in tristique ex, ut fermentum velit. Nam ac lobortis dui, eget aliquam ligula. Vestibulum vel leo in purus tincidunt luctus non ut orci.</p>
        <p>Integer venenatis vestibulum lorem nec ultrices. In eget commodo velit, in vulputate nisi. Aliquam pulvinar dignissim nisl. Pellentesque congue faucibus enim, a malesuada quam molestie nec. Sed lacinia turpis tellus, eu pretium lectus auctor id.
          Sed porta ipsum eu neque volutpat volutpat. Suspendisse rutrum mi felis, nec vulputate velit vulputate quis. Maecenas mollis lobortis neque, nec vehicula orci. Vivamus fringilla volutpat ligula. Proin eu sem eget orci convallis lobortis. Proin
          id orci luctus, elementum velit eget, pulvinar orci.</p>
        <p>Etiam hendrerit ipsum eros, a semper mi fringilla et. Fusce pretium ac lorem in blandit. Nulla facilisi. Nunc orci lectus, cursus eget semper vitae, interdum non turpis. Suspendisse dolor ante, tincidunt eu urna eu, dapibus consectetur dolor.
          In in tortor et lorem euismod semper. Nullam gravida turpis vel commodo ullamcorper. Vestibulum rutrum consequat tortor at blandit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc eget eleifend lectus.
          Duis mollis aliquet ipsum eget tempus.</p>
        <p>Aliquam viverra neque vitae faucibus posuere. Phasellus facilisis nisl vel risus aliquam commodo. Etiam lacinia laoreet sagittis. Mauris dignissim odio sed diam tempor, dapibus condimentum massa cursus. Integer ut nibh commodo, congue tortor vel,
          imperdiet ex. Morbi quis elementum metus, nec consequat purus. Praesent rutrum efficitur tempus. Phasellus hendrerit luctus magna in vehicula. Vestibulum dictum magna nisi, at lacinia lorem vestibulum et.</p>
        <p>Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus at eleifend ligula. Nam sed placerat nisl, a pulvinar ante. Mauris ac laoreet ante. Aliquam pellentesque leo tortor, sed tempor massa egestas quis. Fusce dictum non turpis sed scelerisque. Nunc tristique nisl ac
          ante tristique venenatis. Quisque quis felis rhoncus, porttitor enim sit amet, facilisis quam. Curabitur non erat ac ante faucibus lobortis eget at lorem. Maecenas eget tempus sapien. Curabitur eu luctus nulla, eu luctus ex. Vestibulum sodales
          enim enim, sit amet tempor ligula laoreet at. Etiam est arcu, elementum et sodales non, tincidunt et sapien. Fusce vitae molestie mi, a bibendum felis. Sed nunc mauris, faucibus vel rutrum ut, lacinia sit amet neque.</p>
        <p>Curabitur blandit lacus ut erat cursus luctus quis blandit ex. Duis eget fringilla risus, et egestas ligula. Pellentesque ligula ante, vulputate in faucibus et, efficitur sed mauris. Aliquam at pretium est, nec tempor mauris. Ut pharetra eget
          neque non dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla blandit tellus vel massa elementum, vel consectetur ligula maximus. Vestibulum rutrum magna sit amet dictum mattis. Morbi varius lacus ac imperdiet fringilla. Suspendisse molestie nibh vitae gravida
          sollicitudin. Suspendisse tempor finibus felis, eu sagittis lorem.</p>
        <p>Sed sodales ultrices facilisis. Phasellus vel massa id neque convallis volutpat vitae sed turpis. Sed ac massa dolor. Sed facilisis nulla suscipit commodo venenatis. In bibendum consectetur rutrum. Duis dapibus, risus sit amet semper pharetra,
          erat dui blandit erat, sit amet rutrum ante est nec enim. Pellentesque lobortis ligula sed fringilla dictum. Proin rhoncus, lacus in facilisis pharetra, lorem leo facilisis metus, ac ornare diam risus sed ipsum. Nullam mattis enim nec odio porttitor
          fermentum vel vel mi. Aliquam lacinia consectetur interdum.</p>
      </main>
      <footer style="padding: 8px 16px" class="mdl-mini-footer">
        <div class="mdl-mini-footer__right-section">
          <ul class="mdl-mini-footer__link-list">
            <li>
              <img alt="GitHub" height="32" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CAD97/SO-resources/9ca92a11babb0766580e511d8473b960c040cc91/01/github-32x32.png">
            </li>
            <li>
              <img alt="YouTube" height="32" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CAD97/SO-resources/9ca92a11babb0766580e511d8473b960c040cc91/01/youtube-45x32.png">
            </li>
            <li>
              <img alt="Twitter" height="32" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CAD97/SO-resources/9ca92a11babb0766580e511d8473b960c040cc91/01/twitter-39x32.png">
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the footer *within* the `<main>` element here. All page content goes within the `mdl-layout__content` element. Otherwise the layout javascript is going to mess up and things won't work as expected (as you are seeing.)

Comment: If you can provide where in the docs mdl says that the footer should be used within the layout__content, I will accept this answer.

Comment: The layout usage section says "Your content here" within the content area. We never say to put the footer anywhere specifically, so it should be assumed there. The docs are being worked on for 2.x to make things more direct while we rewrite the components. I'm not incorrect on the content needing to be in `__content`. Some parts work outside of it for layout, but footer isn't a part of layout. You can hack to get it to work outside of layout, but it is a hack and may cause things to not work properly.

Comment: Well, I managed to get it working outside the content element, actually, for the fixed footer which I am going for. I'm adding an answer right now. Maybe that can be used!

Comment: FYI, I am a project maintainer for MDL. That is *not* supported code structure and may cause things to fail that aren't anticipated. Just keep this in mind when something breaks unexpectedly with the footer or layout.

Comment: I apologize for accidentally implying you were incorrect about your own project; and I am aware that my solution here is a hack. (Then again, much of HTML/CSS is a hack... but that's a separate point.) Let's hope 2.x makes everything clearer!

Comment: It's all good. I  just know the layout code fair enough and I know that is going to cause problems if you end up needing to do anything on scroll and get calculations out that are right. And who knows what other things around the web might try to do. Best avoid it where possible, people have already been bitten by it in our issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

This solution retains the "fixed footer" that I had in the question. This means that the footer always displays at the bottom of the screen regardless of how much content is on the page.

The answer [provided by Garbee, a maintainer for MDL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37433808/3019990) recommends putting the footer within the content element. This should be considered the only officially supported layout. However, it pushes the footer to the bottom of the page, which is not my desired behavior.

After playing around with different sticky and fixed footer solutions, I found that applying a `flex` of `0 0 auto` to the `footer` to let Chrome act the same as Firefox. It seems that with a `flex-shrink` of 1, Chrome shrinks the footer when in this position, where Firefox doesn't, and as the default value for `flex` is `0 1 auto`, this caused the footer to be mishapen on Chrome but not Firefox when in this position.

**TL;DR:**

```
.footer {
    -webkit-flex: none;
    -ms-flex: none;
    flex: none;
}
```

```css
.footer {
  -webkit-flex: none;
  -ms-flex: none;
  flex: none;
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: true console: true -->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-- Material Design Lite -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.deep_purple-blue.min.css">
  <script defer="" src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout">
    <header class="mdl-layout__header"></header>
    <div class="mdl-layout__drawer"></div>
    <main class="mdl-layout__content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam egestas, magna ac ultrices hendrerit, risus lorem accumsan justo, at finibus orci odio at sapien. Morbi eu placerat nisl. Nunc rhoncus ut risus nec eleifend. Nulla facilisi. Morbi nec
        nisi facilisis, maximus ligula sed, facilisis enim. Suspendisse fermentum venenatis tincidunt. Maecenas semper consectetur vestibulum. Morbi eget molestie magna. Duis quis neque interdum, elementum risus ac, interdum urna. Nunc fermentum non nulla
        vel pharetra. In ullamcorper ac ipsum ut convallis. Morbi bibendum nisi vitae quam commodo porta.</p>
      <p>Nam facilisis finibus libero vel consequat. Cras eu magna in dui ullamcorper aliquet nec vestibulum mi. Nam rutrum justo ac risus imperdiet consectetur. Donec pellentesque sapien nec euismod ullamcorper. Nam efficitur quam vitae justo convallis,
        a aliquet justo finibus. Pellentesque auctor finibus neque sed dapibus. Ut maximus interdum risus ut viverra. Quisque varius, augue et cursus efficitur, nisl arcu maximus sapien, vel tempor erat elit at turpis. Nullam imperdiet urna eget elit
        dignissim, ut feugiat nibh lacinia. Aliquam vel cursus est. Praesent tristique mauris a ex viverra, at vehicula nibh laoreet.</p>
      <p>Curabitur lacinia, justo ac placerat porta, lectus nulla aliquam nisi, sit amet elementum enim ipsum vitae tortor. Donec eu ultrices tellus. Nam et quam nisl. Nulla facilisi. Donec turpis velit, tristique et ultrices sit amet, blandit vel tellus.
        Nam ultricies posuere odio in pretium. Integer semper, lacus at pulvinar condimentum, nibh nibh ornare dui, vel tincidunt mauris turpis at sapien. Nunc ultrices sollicitudin diam ut semper. Nulla quis quam fringilla, pretium erat eu, hendrerit
        tellus. Ut lacinia elit eu leo lobortis tincidunt. Sed vel gravida purus. Fusce ultrices libero ante, sit amet finibus sem eleifend ac. Etiam ullamcorper placerat orci, id vulputate sapien blandit eget. Proin eget hendrerit tellus, sit amet venenatis
        dui.
      </p>
      <p>Nullam ut diam et ante euismod suscipit. Sed aliquet rutrum pharetra. Sed quis orci malesuada, elementum tellus id, aliquet eros. Donec ut nisl sit amet erat ornare finibus. Aliquam id tincidunt augue. Sed tincidunt maximus sem at dictum. Fusce
        in quam efficitur, finibus sapien a, convallis felis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus tristique auctor diam, euismod cursus mi. Phasellus quis posuere
        mi. Integer ut rhoncus massa. Curabitur quis consequat sapien, sit amet malesuada mauris. Vestibulum in tristique ex, ut fermentum velit. Nam ac lobortis dui, eget aliquam ligula. Vestibulum vel leo in purus tincidunt luctus non ut orci.</p>
      <p>Integer venenatis vestibulum lorem nec ultrices. In eget commodo velit, in vulputate nisi. Aliquam pulvinar dignissim nisl. Pellentesque congue faucibus enim, a malesuada quam molestie nec. Sed lacinia turpis tellus, eu pretium lectus auctor id.
        Sed porta ipsum eu neque volutpat volutpat. Suspendisse rutrum mi felis, nec vulputate velit vulputate quis. Maecenas mollis lobortis neque, nec vehicula orci. Vivamus fringilla volutpat ligula. Proin eu sem eget orci convallis lobortis. Proin
        id orci luctus, elementum velit eget, pulvinar orci.</p>
      <p>Etiam hendrerit ipsum eros, a semper mi fringilla et. Fusce pretium ac lorem in blandit. Nulla facilisi. Nunc orci lectus, cursus eget semper vitae, interdum non turpis. Suspendisse dolor ante, tincidunt eu urna eu, dapibus consectetur dolor. In
        in tortor et lorem euismod semper. Nullam gravida turpis vel commodo ullamcorper. Vestibulum rutrum consequat tortor at blandit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc eget eleifend lectus. Duis
        mollis aliquet ipsum eget tempus.</p>
      <p>Aliquam viverra neque vitae faucibus posuere. Phasellus facilisis nisl vel risus aliquam commodo. Etiam lacinia laoreet sagittis. Mauris dignissim odio sed diam tempor, dapibus condimentum massa cursus. Integer ut nibh commodo, congue tortor vel,
        imperdiet ex. Morbi quis elementum metus, nec consequat purus. Praesent rutrum efficitur tempus. Phasellus hendrerit luctus magna in vehicula. Vestibulum dictum magna nisi, at lacinia lorem vestibulum et.</p>
      <p>Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus at eleifend ligula. Nam sed placerat nisl, a pulvinar ante. Mauris ac laoreet ante. Aliquam pellentesque leo tortor, sed tempor massa egestas quis. Fusce dictum non turpis sed scelerisque. Nunc tristique nisl ac
        ante tristique venenatis. Quisque quis felis rhoncus, porttitor enim sit amet, facilisis quam. Curabitur non erat ac ante faucibus lobortis eget at lorem. Maecenas eget tempus sapien. Curabitur eu luctus nulla, eu luctus ex. Vestibulum sodales
        enim enim, sit amet tempor ligula laoreet at. Etiam est arcu, elementum et sodales non, tincidunt et sapien. Fusce vitae molestie mi, a bibendum felis. Sed nunc mauris, faucibus vel rutrum ut, lacinia sit amet neque.</p>
      <p>Curabitur blandit lacus ut erat cursus luctus quis blandit ex. Duis eget fringilla risus, et egestas ligula. Pellentesque ligula ante, vulputate in faucibus et, efficitur sed mauris. Aliquam at pretium est, nec tempor mauris. Ut pharetra eget neque
        non dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla blandit tellus vel massa elementum, vel consectetur ligula maximus. Vestibulum rutrum magna sit amet dictum mattis. Morbi varius lacus ac imperdiet fringilla. Suspendisse molestie nibh vitae gravida sollicitudin.
        Suspendisse tempor finibus felis, eu sagittis lorem.</p>
      <p>Sed sodales ultrices facilisis. Phasellus vel massa id neque convallis volutpat vitae sed turpis. Sed ac massa dolor. Sed facilisis nulla suscipit commodo venenatis. In bibendum consectetur rutrum. Duis dapibus, risus sit amet semper pharetra, erat
        dui blandit erat, sit amet rutrum ante est nec enim. Pellentesque lobortis ligula sed fringilla dictum. Proin rhoncus, lacus in facilisis pharetra, lorem leo facilisis metus, ac ornare diam risus sed ipsum. Nullam mattis enim nec odio porttitor
        fermentum vel vel mi. Aliquam lacinia consectetur interdum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam egestas, magna ac ultrices hendrerit, risus lorem accumsan justo, at finibus orci odio at sapien. Morbi eu placerat nisl. Nunc rhoncus ut risus nec eleifend. Nulla facilisi. Morbi nec
        nisi facilisis, maximus ligula sed, facilisis enim. Suspendisse fermentum venenatis tincidunt. Maecenas semper consectetur vestibulum. Morbi eget molestie magna. Duis quis neque interdum, elementum risus ac, interdum urna. Nunc fermentum non nulla
        vel pharetra. In ullamcorper ac ipsum ut convallis. Morbi bibendum nisi vitae quam commodo porta.</p>
      <p>Nam facilisis finibus libero vel consequat. Cras eu magna in dui ullamcorper aliquet nec vestibulum mi. Nam rutrum justo ac risus imperdiet consectetur. Donec pellentesque sapien nec euismod ullamcorper. Nam efficitur quam vitae justo convallis,
        a aliquet justo finibus. Pellentesque auctor finibus neque sed dapibus. Ut maximus interdum risus ut viverra. Quisque varius, augue et cursus efficitur, nisl arcu maximus sapien, vel tempor erat elit at turpis. Nullam imperdiet urna eget elit
        dignissim, ut feugiat nibh lacinia. Aliquam vel cursus est. Praesent tristique mauris a ex viverra, at vehicula nibh laoreet.</p>
      <p>Curabitur lacinia, justo ac placerat porta, lectus nulla aliquam nisi, sit amet elementum enim ipsum vitae tortor. Donec eu ultrices tellus. Nam et quam nisl. Nulla facilisi. Donec turpis velit, tristique et ultrices sit amet, blandit vel tellus.
        Nam ultricies posuere odio in pretium. Integer semper, lacus at pulvinar condimentum, nibh nibh ornare dui, vel tincidunt mauris turpis at sapien. Nunc ultrices sollicitudin diam ut semper. Nulla quis quam fringilla, pretium erat eu, hendrerit
        tellus. Ut lacinia elit eu leo lobortis tincidunt. Sed vel gravida purus. Fusce ultrices libero ante, sit amet finibus sem eleifend ac. Etiam ullamcorper placerat orci, id vulputate sapien blandit eget. Proin eget hendrerit tellus, sit amet venenatis
        dui.
      </p>
      <p>Nullam ut diam et ante euismod suscipit. Sed aliquet rutrum pharetra. Sed quis orci malesuada, elementum tellus id, aliquet eros. Donec ut nisl sit amet erat ornare finibus. Aliquam id tincidunt augue. Sed tincidunt maximus sem at dictum. Fusce
        in quam efficitur, finibus sapien a, convallis felis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus tristique auctor diam, euismod cursus mi. Phasellus quis posuere
        mi. Integer ut rhoncus massa. Curabitur quis consequat sapien, sit amet malesuada mauris. Vestibulum in tristique ex, ut fermentum velit. Nam ac lobortis dui, eget aliquam ligula. Vestibulum vel leo in purus tincidunt luctus non ut orci.</p>
      <p>Integer venenatis vestibulum lorem nec ultrices. In eget commodo velit, in vulputate nisi. Aliquam pulvinar dignissim nisl. Pellentesque congue faucibus enim, a malesuada quam molestie nec. Sed lacinia turpis tellus, eu pretium lectus auctor id.
        Sed porta ipsum eu neque volutpat volutpat. Suspendisse rutrum mi felis, nec vulputate velit vulputate quis. Maecenas mollis lobortis neque, nec vehicula orci. Vivamus fringilla volutpat ligula. Proin eu sem eget orci convallis lobortis. Proin
        id orci luctus, elementum velit eget, pulvinar orci.</p>
      <p>Etiam hendrerit ipsum eros, a semper mi fringilla et. Fusce pretium ac lorem in blandit. Nulla facilisi. Nunc orci lectus, cursus eget semper vitae, interdum non turpis. Suspendisse dolor ante, tincidunt eu urna eu, dapibus consectetur dolor. In
        in tortor et lorem euismod semper. Nullam gravida turpis vel commodo ullamcorper. Vestibulum rutrum consequat tortor at blandit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc eget eleifend lectus. Duis
        mollis aliquet ipsum eget tempus.</p>
      <p>Aliquam viverra neque vitae faucibus posuere. Phasellus facilisis nisl vel risus aliquam commodo. Etiam lacinia laoreet sagittis. Mauris dignissim odio sed diam tempor, dapibus condimentum massa cursus. Integer ut nibh commodo, congue tortor vel,
        imperdiet ex. Morbi quis elementum metus, nec consequat purus. Praesent rutrum efficitur tempus. Phasellus hendrerit luctus magna in vehicula. Vestibulum dictum magna nisi, at lacinia lorem vestibulum et.</p>
      <p>Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus at eleifend ligula. Nam sed placerat nisl, a pulvinar ante. Mauris ac laoreet ante. Aliquam pellentesque leo tortor, sed tempor massa egestas quis. Fusce dictum non turpis sed scelerisque. Nunc tristique nisl ac
        ante tristique venenatis. Quisque quis felis rhoncus, porttitor enim sit amet, facilisis quam. Curabitur non erat ac ante faucibus lobortis eget at lorem. Maecenas eget tempus sapien. Curabitur eu luctus nulla, eu luctus ex. Vestibulum sodales
        enim enim, sit amet tempor ligula laoreet at. Etiam est arcu, elementum et sodales non, tincidunt et sapien. Fusce vitae molestie mi, a bibendum felis. Sed nunc mauris, faucibus vel rutrum ut, lacinia sit amet neque.</p>
      <p>Curabitur blandit lacus ut erat cursus luctus quis blandit ex. Duis eget fringilla risus, et egestas ligula. Pellentesque ligula ante, vulputate in faucibus et, efficitur sed mauris. Aliquam at pretium est, nec tempor mauris. Ut pharetra eget neque
        non dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla blandit tellus vel massa elementum, vel consectetur ligula maximus. Vestibulum rutrum magna sit amet dictum mattis. Morbi varius lacus ac imperdiet fringilla. Suspendisse molestie nibh vitae gravida sollicitudin.
        Suspendisse tempor finibus felis, eu sagittis lorem.</p>
      <p>Sed sodales ultrices facilisis. Phasellus vel massa id neque convallis volutpat vitae sed turpis. Sed ac massa dolor. Sed facilisis nulla suscipit commodo venenatis. In bibendum consectetur rutrum. Duis dapibus, risus sit amet semper pharetra, erat
        dui blandit erat, sit amet rutrum ante est nec enim. Pellentesque lobortis ligula sed fringilla dictum. Proin rhoncus, lacus in facilisis pharetra, lorem leo facilisis metus, ac ornare diam risus sed ipsum. Nullam mattis enim nec odio porttitor
        fermentum vel vel mi. Aliquam lacinia consectetur interdum.</p>
    </main>
    <footer class="mdl-mini-footer" style="padding:8px 16px;">
      <div class="mdl-mini-footer__right-section">
        <ul class="mdl-mini-footer__link-list">
          <li>
            <img alt="GitHub" height="32" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CAD97/SO-resources/9ca92a11babb0766580e511d8473b960c040cc91/01/github-32x32.png">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img alt="YouTube" height="32" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CAD97/SO-resources/9ca92a11babb0766580e511d8473b960c040cc91/01/youtube-45x32.png">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img alt="Twitter" height="32" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CAD97/SO-resources/9ca92a11babb0766580e511d8473b960c040cc91/01/twitter-39x32.png">
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Garbee's answer does not fix the problem if the main content within `mdl-layout_content` is not long enough to scroll : the `mdl-mini-footer` will not be at the bottom of the page.

To ensure that the `mdl-mini-footer` will stick the bottom of you page even if you do not have content (for exemple if you have dynamical content) make sure to put the footer in another `main` element :

```
<body class="mdl-base">
   <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout">
      <main class="mdl-layout__content">
         //Your content here
      </main>
      <main>
         <footer class="mdl-mini-footer footer">
            // Your footer here        
         </footer>
      </main>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: [The HTML spec does not allow for multiple `<main>` elements.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwjFh6Pulu_RAhUCKCYKHbpWCIcQFggMMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FHTML%2FElement%2Fmain&usg=AFQjCNEmjmS4wcVKnTJ2GbYnofB5XAF2bg&sig2=NPGwB5qszBe3szh1SP4Hwg) It may work, but it's not well-formed, and as such could break in subtle ways without warning.

Answer (score -1):

you have used `display: flex;` on `.mdl-mini-footer` which is creating problem remove it and height will be ok

Comment: Disabling `dislay: -webkit-flex;` and `display: flex;` on `.mdl-mini-footer` through the Chrome developer tools does indeed fix the height, but also causes the `.mdl-mini-footer__right-section` to display on the left of the footer rather than the right, as it is supposed to. (Also, note that all css classes starting with `mdl` are part of Material Design Lite and not directly modifiable by me.)